# The supplied phased action failed with an exception. A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'

Tags: java, android, flutter, build, android-gradle-plugin

The supplied phased action failed with an exception.
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.5.
Searched in the following locations:

- https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/7.5/gradle-7.5.pom
- https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/7.5/gradle-7.5.pom
  Required by:
  project :

fix it from android studio

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.